# Display only one image in a div

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to display an image that I loop it from the folder.

```
<div class="blah">
<% System.IO.FileInfo[] files = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/MyPath/"))
.GetFiles();
var exefiles = from System.IO.FileInfo f in files
               where f.Extension == ".jpg" ||f.Extension == ".jpeg" 
               || f.Extension == "JPG" 
               select f;
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in exefiles) { %>
   <img src="blahblah.jpg" />
<% } %>
</div>
```

Problem : The div display all the images that store in the folder.

But I want to display only 1 image in my div.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you have multiple jpg in the folder, how do you determine which one to display?

Comment: you want to display each image in a separate div?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do this with [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String) (System.IO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)

something like:

```
<div class="blah">
<% 
    string path = "images/";
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path), "*jp*g");
    if (files.Length > 0) { %>
    <img src="<%= path + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files[0])%>" />
<%  } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is error while I put those block. This is error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: sounds like the value you're passing in isn't a string for some reason, in my example `files[0]` is a string, did you make some adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any login inside your view, that's why it's called Model View Controller. Put your logic inside the Action and pass it to the view inside the model or the ViewBag.